# Django Custom User with Array of Another Model (Acting like a shopping cart)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

Newbie to Django, Django rest_framework, and Djoser here.

I am building the backend to what you can think of as a simple shopping app (think coffeeshop on this one). At the moment, I have a custom User model in one app called `authapp` and a Coffee model that lives in another app called `apiapp`. My goal is to allow User objects to have 0-infinity number of Coffee objects to act as their shopping cart and to have that data displayed in the users endpoint.

Currently, I the User model looks like the following in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    coffees = models.ManyToManyField("apiapp.Coffee", verbose_name="coffee")
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
```

In `serializers.py`, I have:

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

# Create your serializers here

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        field = ['id', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'coffee']
```

In the admin dashboard, I currently see this when editing a User object (looks like you can select and deselect any / all of the coffee objects I have created):

[image]

At the all users endpoint this is what I see (it is missing the array of coffee objects):

[image]

This all leaves me with two questions.

1. How can I implement a list type functionality to hold the Coffee items within user? I want to be able to add as many or as little of one Coffee object as possible.
2. How do I use the serializer.py class to display that array of Coffee objects in the users endpoint? Currently that

Answer (score 0):

1. A Many to Many field is a reasonable choice for this, assuming the same `Coffee` record can be linked to multiple `User` records.
2. The reason coffees is not showing in your serialiser class is that the field should be `'coffees'` not `'coffee'` in your field list. You may also want to play with the [depth meta value](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) if you want to see more than just the ID of each coffee.

Comment: Though your changes make sense, I tried them and still no luck.

Comment: There are other fields in your field list that are not showing up in the API view screenshot. Are you sure the API view is accessing the `UserCreateSerializer` and not something else?

Comment: Other than password, it looks like all the fields are there. I am covering the email field in the photo.

Comment: True, though they are also in a different order. Have you checked the output of a regular UserSerializer class, instead of the create variant?

Comment: You hate to see it, but I have figured out the issue. In my serializer class I used the key `field` when I was supposed to be using `fields` . Problem solved.

Comment: Ahh that's unfortunate. Should've spotted it myself. Glad you worked it out though.